# Why does the compiler allow throws when the method will never throw the Exception

Tags: java, checked-exceptions

I am wondering why the java compiler allows throws in the method declaration when the method will never throw the Exception. Because "throws" is a way of handling the exception (telling the caller to handle it).

Since there are two ways of handling exception (throws & try/catch). In a try/catch, it doesn't allow the catch of an exception not thrown in the try block but it allows a throws in a method that does may not throw the exception.

```
private static void methodA() {
    try {
        // Do something
        // No IO operation here
    } catch (IOException ex) {  //This line does not compile because
                              //exception is never thrown from try
        // Handle   
    }
}

private static void methodB() throws IOException { //Why does this //compile when excetion is never thrown in function body
    //Do Something 
    //No IO operation
}
```

Comment: TLDR: **it's a design choice**, and there isn't right or wrong here.

Comment: As we are not the designers of the language, "why" questions would be hard to answer with anything but speculative, *opinion-based* answers.

Comment: I also find the term `throws` to be misleading. I parse it as `could_throw` in my mind now and it seems to fit better with its behaviour.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `throws` clause is part of the method's contract. It requires the caller of the method to behave as if the specified exception may be thrown by the method (i.e. either catch the exception or declare their own `throws` clause).

It's possible that the initial version of a method does not throw the exception specified in the `throws` clause, but a future version can throw it without breaking the API (i.e. any existing code that calls the method will still pass compilation).

The opposite it also possible. If the method used to throw the exception specified in the `throws` clause, but a future version of it doesn't throw it anymore, you should keep the `throws` clause in order not to break existing code that uses your method.

First example:

Suppose you have this code which uses `methodB`:

```
private static void methodA() {
    methodB(); // doesn't have throws IOException clause yet
}
```

If later you want to change `methodB` to throw `IOException`, `methodA` will stop passing compilation.

Second example:

Suppose you have this code which uses `methodB`:

```
private static void methodA() {
    try {
        methodB(); // throws IOException
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
```

If you remove the `throws` clause from a future version of `methodB`, `methodA` won't pass compilation anymore.

This example is not very interesting when `methodA` is `private`, because it can only be used locally (within the same class, where it's easy to modify all the methods that call it).

However, if it becomes `public`, you don't know who uses (or will use) your method, so you have no control of all the code that may break as a result of adding or removing the `throws` clause.

And if it's an instance method, there's another reason for allowing the `throws` clause even if you don't throw the exception - the method can be overridden, and the overriding method may throw the exception even if the base class implementation does not.

Comment: The last point about the override should be given more emphasis, IMHO.  The notion of "what if functions change" is less concrete than the notion of "even though the parent function would have no reason to throw a particular exceptions, even *today's* versions of child functions might need to do so.

Comment: @supercat agreed, but the code in the question has static methods, which cannot be overridden,  which is why most my answer gives reasons that apply to static methods.

Answer (score 8):

Because the signature defines the contract of the method. Even if the method doesn't throw an IOException now, maybe it will in the future, and you want to prepare for that possibility.

Suppose you just provide a dummy implementation for the method for now, but you know that, later, the actual implementation will potentially throw an IOException.
If the compiler prevented you from adding this throws clause, you would be forced to rework all the calls (recursively) to that method once you provide the actual implementation of the method.

Comment: It's debatable whether a private method can be said to have a contract.

Comment: It defines a contract for all the other methods in the class. And these methods might, in turn,want to declare an IOException because they rely on the contract of the private method they call.

Comment: You can also decide to change the return value of a private method. That's also part of the "contract", isn't it? And yet, what you do when that happens is fix the code that calls it. The same could have been done with "throws".

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the question, which is: why does the compiler allow to have a throws clause for an exception that is not thrown by the method. What's your point? The compiler also allows you to use `long` as the return type even if you only ever return constant values that fit into an int. Why? For the same reason: you define the contract, which is that the method may, now or later, return a long value.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword throws tells programmer that there could be an IOException happening in the method. Now if you didn't specify try/catch it means that when exception is thrown program will stop working, while in try/catch you handle it by doing something else if thrown exception.

Use throws for readability and specifying the possibility of exception and use try/catch to tell program what to do in case of exception.

Answer (score -1):

1. The methodB throws IOException, so the method calling methodB is responsible for catching the exception which will be thrown by methodB. Try calling methodB from other methods, it will ask you to catch it or re-throw the IOException. Somewhere you will have to catch the IOException in the chain (in try/catch block). **So you wont get compile time error**.

   private void sampleMethod(){
       try {
           methodB();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
2. try/catch in methodA admittedly swallows the exception, that means methodA is responsible for catching the exception in try/catch block. 
   "*Every statement in any java program must be reachable i.e every statement must be executable at least once*"
   So, you will get compiler error as your try block doesn't have any code to cause IOException.